# Why is bash not interactive after setting &shell='/bin/bash -i'?

Tags: bash

My vimrc sets the shell option:

```
let &shell='/bin/bash -i'
```

which I confirm using

```
echo &shell
```

The `-i` makes the shell interactive.  I want to do this so that it runs `~/.bashrc`, which contains the setting

```
shopt -s extglob
```

However, `extglob` was not being set because `~/.bashrc` was not being run, which in turn seems to be because the shell is not interactive.  I determined this by putting the vim cursor on each the following lines

```
echo $-
echo $PS1
```

and issuing the normal mode command `!!bash`.  According to [the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html), the string returned by the first command should include the letter `i` if the shell is interactive, while the string returned by the second command should include the text and control characters for the prompt that is shown at the bash command line (as opposed to nothing).  Both tests show the shell to be not interactive.

Why would the `-i` flag in the shell option be ignored?  What further troubleshooting steps can I take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test is flawed. If you run `!!bash`, you're calling just the `bash` command explicitly. Why would you expect `bash` to be interactive in that case?

`!!` is shorthand for `:.!`, so you're running `:.!bash`, which would become something like: `bash -i -c 'bash'`. So the first `bash` might have `extglob` set, but the second won't.

Run `:!echo $-` for a better test:

```
himBHc

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

In this case, the command run by Vim would look like: `bash -i -c 'echo $-'`.

If you do want to test with `!!`, use the `pstree` command (`pstree -psa $$`) to see what the parent process is. In my case, the relevant part is:

```
  `-vim,13387
      `-bash,13527 -i -c (bash) < /tmp/vAaJ5gB/7 >/tmp/vAaJ5gB/8 2>&1
          `-bash,13530
              `-pstree,13531 -psa 13530
```

As you can see, Vim did call it with `-i`.

Or just run `:!shopt nullglob`:

```
nullglob        on

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

---

By the way, the Vim way to add an option to the shell being used to run `:!` commands is [`shellcmdflag`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shellcmdflag%27). From [`:h :!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21):

```
On Unix the command normally runs in a non-interactive
shell.  If you want an interactive shell to be used
(to use aliases) set 'shellcmdflag' to "-ic".
```

---

From [the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Invoked-non_002dinteractively),

> #### Invoked non-interactively
>
> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
>   example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment,
>   expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
>   the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the
>   following command were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the `PATH` variable is not used to search for the
>   filename.

So a simple way to affect invocations of `!!bash`, would be to set `BASH_ENV=~/.bash_extra`:

```
let $BASH_ENV="~/.bash_extra"
```

where `~/.bash_extra` would contain (among any other settings you need):

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Using an interactive shell has undesirable effects, like the output being cluttered with your prompt. This avoids that.

Comment: Hi, muru: Yes, what you said was beginning to dawn on me. I put in a test of extglob in my bashrc, then did `!!bash` when the vim cursor was on `shopt extglob`. I got conflicting extglob statuses, one on the vim command line, and another replacing the cursor line. So the shelling out was interactive, but the invocation of bash in `!!bash` was not.  Would you be able to complete your answer with an indication of how one might replace a bunch of contiguous lines in the vim buffer with the result of the execution of those lines by an interactive bash shell?

Comment: `:. w !bash` doesn't do it (as an example of applying this to the single-line range `.,.`.   P.S. At this point, I only want the interactiveness to apply when shelling out from vim.  I don't want to figure out the rat's nest of possible side-effects if I *always* have bash start interactively.

Comment: @user2153235 why not just `!!bash -i`?

Comment: Tried it. There is some weird side effect where I get 11 repetitions of prompt control characters followed by `$Use "exit" to leave the shell.`.  If this is the only way, I have some troubleshooting ahead of me.

Comment: @user2153235 Hmm, in my case I get the output in the file as expected. O.o Can you explain what is it you're trying to achieve? If the aim is to just have `shopt -s nullglob` for some commands in your current file, why not add `shopt -s nullglob` as the first command?

Comment: I often have a log file (like a lab journal, capturing stream of thought) together with commands that I temporarily assemble for the sole purpose of running through bash in order to capture the output in the same log file.  I added a diagnostic message to my `~/.bashrc` to determine if the 11 repeated messages was due to recursive invocation of `~/.bashrc`, but it wasn't.  If I bang out on a line `echo dog`, the 11 repetitions occur after the `dog` message.

Comment: Works like a charm, muru.  Thank you for that, and for the hint about setting shell options for `:!` commands.